# Is there a way to achieve pagination in AMP pages?

Tags: amp-html

I want to build AMP Page for https://doubtnut.com/ncert-solutions/class-6-maths-1 . I there a way to achieve pagination in AMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **load-more** attribute of [amp-list](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list?format=websites).

For working examples, please see [test/manual/amp-list/infinite-scroll-1.amp.html](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/test/manual/amp-list/infinite-scroll-1.amp.html) and [test/manual/amp-list/infinite-scroll-2.amp.html](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/test/manual/amp-list/infinite-scroll-1.amp.html).